# CVOpenGLESTextureCache vs glTexSubImage2D on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

My OpenGL app uses OpenGL to render a texture in full screen and updates part of it at regular intervals. So far, I've been using glTexImage2D to push my initial texture and then I update the dirty regions with glTexSubImage2D. To do that, I'm using single buffering. This works well.

I've seen that there might be another way to achieve the same thing using CVOpenGLESTextureCache. The textures held in the texture cache reference a CVPixelBuffer. I'd like to know if I can mutate these cached textures. I tried to recreate a CVOpenGLESTexture for each update but this decreases my frame rate dramatically (not surprising after all since I'm not specifying the dirty region anywhere). Maybe I totally misunderstood the use case for this texture cache.

Can someone provide some guidance?

UPDATE: Here is the code I'm using. The first update works fine. The subsequent updates don't (nothing happens). Between each update I modify the raw bitmap.

```
if (firstUpdate) {

    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, ctx, NULL, &texCache);

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL, width_, height_, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, bitmap, width_*4, NULL, 0, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture = NULL;
    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, texCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, width_, height_, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &texture);

    texture_[0] = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
}


CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(texCache, 0);

if (firstUpdate) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

if (firstUpdate) {
    static const float textureVertices[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0
    };

    static const float textureCoords[] = {
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0
    };

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &textureVertices[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoords);
}

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

firstUpdate = false;
```

Comment: Yeah, you really don't want to recreate the cached texture or pixel buffer for each update, but instead create it once and reuse it for your updates. There's some overhead in the creation of this pixel buffer and texture. Once you have that texture, you should be able to update it by writing to the pixel buffer's bytes, because those should be directly mapped to the texture's internal bytes.

Comment: That's what I thought but couldn't get that working... I managed to push my initial texture to the screen by wrapping my bitmap in a pixel buffer. I then retain the texture cache, the texture itself, and the pixel buffer. Next thing I do is to update my underlying bitmap and redraw my OpenGL quad. However, nothing happened...

Comment: I have tested every variation I can think of and I have found the same results as you on Sim, iPhone4, and an iPad2. It does not seem to matter if CVPixelBufferCreate() or CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes() is used to create the cv buffer. Calling CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes will upload 1 frame (the initial state of the user buffer), but writing to the mapped data memory has no effect. I actually found that if you delete and recreate the texture on every frame, the CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage() API just ends up spending all its time in glTexImage2D_Exec doing the upload.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing quite a bit of hacking with these texture APIs and I finally was able to produce a working example of writing to a texture via memory using the texture cache API. These APIs work on the iOS device but not on the simulator, so a special workaround was needed (basically just calling glTexSubImage2D() explicitly in the simulator). The code needed to double buffer the texture loading done in another thread to avoid updating while rendering was going on. The full source code and timing results are at [opengl_write_texture_cache](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post12_opengl_write_texture_cache/index.html). The linked Xcode project decodes from PNGs and the performance on older iPhone hardware is a little poor as a result. But the code is free to do whatever you want with, so it should not be hard to adapt to some other pixel source. To only write a dirty region, only write to that portion of the memory buffer in the background thread.