# Fast Texture Data Update on iOS

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I need to update texture data for one texture at every frame. Is there any  way of doing this very fast? The best option for me would be something similar with GL_APPLE_client_storage, but this is not supported on iOS. The obvious solution is to call glTexImage2D every frame, but this will copy the data and also I will have to keep same texture 2 times in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture caches (added in iOS 5.0) provide the equivalent functionality to `GL_APPLE_client_storage` on iOS. On initial creation, they do seem to trigger `glTexImage2D()`, but I believe that subsequent updates behave in the manner of the Mac's `GL_APPLE_client_storage`.

They provide a particular performance boost when dealing with camera frames, as AV Foundation is optimized for this case. I describe how this works in detail within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544293/where-is-the-official-documentation-for-cvopenglestexture-method-types/9574798#9574798) for the camera. For raw data, you can create your own CVPixelBufferRef to be used for this, and then write to its internal contents to update the texture directly.

You have to be a little careful with this, as you can be overwriting texture data while a scene is being rendered, leading to tearing and other artifacts.

Comment: I was under the impression that the new texture cache feature was there to support having hardware like the h.264 decoder or the camera write directly into video memory via CoreVideo, then when CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage() is invoked the texture data would not need to be uploaded again because it is already in video memory. If I just create a CV pixel buffer from bytes and create a texture cache, it still uploads the bytes. The key feature of the apple client storage is that it does not upload the bytes, they stay in memory. But, a texture cache approach seem to need a memcpy

Comment: @MoDJ - At least for reads from the texture caches, they clearly do reflect the current state of the backing bytes for a texture. You can read from these bytes on the CPU side while rendering is taking place and even see the tiles being filled in to the target texture in real time. This, combined with the speed of access, speak against memory being copied at least on reads from these mapped pixel buffers. You can also see from memory usage that bytes are not duplicated between the pixel buffer and textures in the manner they would be using `glReadPixels()`.

Comment: I am quite sure you are correct about reading pixels back from the cached texture. But, once a mapping of a texture cache has been setup, one would still need to memcpy() into that mapped memory in order to write the data into the cache, correct? This seems to be the key issue since for a large texture upload, the actual copy into video memory is the bottleneck for something like a movie where 1 texture after another is uploaded to the GPU.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813442/cvopenglestexturecache-vs-gltexsubimage2d-on-ios for a code example of writes to the mapped buffer not making it into the texture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `glTexSubImage2D` to update Texture. See [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Updating_a_texture)