# How to share CVOpenGLESTextureCache between UIView and another thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiview, opengl-es

This is a question for Rhythmic Fistman or anyone who knows the answer:

According to thread: [How to use OpenGL ES on a separate thread on iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253145/how-to-use-opengl-es-on-a-separate-thread-on-iphone)

Rhythmic Fistman found that "iOS5's CVOpenGLESTextureCaches essentially make texture uploads free so I don't need shareGroups anymore and my code is simpler and faster."

I am currently working on an app, that draws 3D graphics and saves it in a movie file. From my understanding, UIView's OpenGL ES framebuffer must be backed with a colorRenderBuffer instead of CVOpenGLESTextureCache, which is the way a movie file saves the opengl texture of the 3D graphics.

I don't want OpenGLES to render the same 3D graphics twice, and I want to share the result of the rendering.

Can you please share your knowledge and/or source code of how to use CVOpenGLESTextureCache to share between a worker thread that saves the openGL texture and the main thread's UIView that display the framebuffer?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Howard

===========Update========

Thanks, I followed Brad's answer and RosyWriter sample code by writing some simple code by rendering both the final buffer and main UIView from the avCaptureOutput Dispatch queue Thread. (Will polish it later).

There are 2 OpenGL-ES 2.0 context, 1 mainContext created for UIWebView, 2 workingContext, created for avCaptureOutput's dispatch queue. They share the same group.

So far so good. Will try to see if the screen tearing effect occur or not.

Thanks so much!

Below is my code:

```
//Draw texture
-(void)Draw:(CVPixelBufferRef)updatedImageBuffer
{
    CVOpenGLESTextureRef cvTexture;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //first draw graphics to the CVPixelBufferRef
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //creates a live binding between the image buffer and the underlying texture object.
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(
                                                                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                cvTextureCache,
                                                                updatedImageBuffer,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                GL_RGBA,//  opengl format
                                                                esContext.bufWidth,
                                                                esContext.bufHeight,
                                                                GL_BGRA,// native iOS format
                                                                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                                0,
                                                                &cvTexture);
    if (err == kCVReturnSuccess) {
        assert(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(cvTexture) == GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GLint texId = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(cvTexture);
        if (!workingContext || [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:workingContext] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"SwapBuffers: [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:workingContext] failed");
            return;
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, workerFrameBuffer);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);

        GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if ( status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {

            drawGraphics(&esContext);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            //glFlush();

            /////////////////////////////////////////////
            //then draw the texture to the main UIView
            /////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (!mainContext || [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:mainContext] == NO) {
                NSLog(@"SwapBuffers: [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:mainContext] failed");
                return;
            }
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

            // Set texture parameters
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mainFrameBuffer);

            status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
            if ( status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {

                // Draw the texture on the screen with OpenGL ES 2
                drawUIView(&esContext, textureVertices);

                // Present the UIView
                glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, mainColorBuffer);
                [mainContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            }
            //glFlush();
        }
        //Flush textureCache
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(cvTextureCache, 0);

        //Release created texture
        CFRelease(cvTexture);
    }
}

void drawUIView( ESContext *esContext, const GLfloat* textureVertices)
{
    UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    // Set the view port to the entire view
    glViewport(0, 0, esContext->viewWidth, esContext->viewHeight);

    // Clear the color buffer
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Use shader program.
    glUseProgram(userData->passThroughProgram);

    // Update attribute values.
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);

    // Update uniform values if there are any
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
///
// Draw a triangle using the shader pair created in Init()
//
void drawGraphics ( ESContext *esContext )
{
    UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
    static const GLfloat vVertices[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };

    // Set the viewport
    glViewport ( 0, 0, esContext->bufWidth, esContext->bufHeight );

    // Clear the color buffer
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Use the program object
    glUseProgram ( userData->graphicsProgram );

    // Load the vertex data
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );

    glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pixel buffer from a texture cache must be associated with a texture, so you can't use it directly with a CAEAGLLayer render target.

However, you can avoid rendering the same scene twice by rendering the scene to your CVOpenGLESTextureCache-associated texture, then render that texture to the screen in your CAEAGLLayer with a simple quad and passthrough shader. This has a small impact on rendering performance, more than offset by the ability to avoid `glReadPixels()` for extracting scene information for movie recording.

Comment: Thanks so much. Basically what you are saying is what Apple's RosyWriter example does. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

There is a big problem. OpenGL-ES EAGLContext switch from main thread to worker thread will need mutex to lock them to avoid hardware driver to render wrong result? B/c there is only 1 hardware resource. Everytime main thread/worker thread needs to draw, it must call [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:currentContext]

That will become a bottleneck. Do you have a way to get around that problem?

Comment: @Howy - Well, technically, you can access the bytes from your pixel buffer in any thread, not just the one that is current for your OpenGL ES context. However, you'll notice if you do so that you'll get screen tearing when recording off of this buffer due to rendering taking place while your movie writer is reading the bytes from the pixel buffer. No matter what, you'll need to use a blocking `glFinish()` right before reading, on your rendering OpenGL ES context. For this, I use a serial dispatch queue and wrap my accessed to one OpenGL ES context in blocks dispatched to that queue.

Comment: This is extremely lightweight, and avoids expensive locks around a shared context. I use this in my image processing framework, as well as my molecular modeler, for operations that run at a smooth 60 FPS.